# Custom tag value in Google Analytics for DNN (DotNetNuke)

Tags: javascript, html, google-analytics, dotnetnuke

we are using Google Analytics script on all pages below:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    var gaJsHost = (("https:" == document.location.protocol) ? "https://ssl." : "http://www.");
    document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='" + gaJsHost + "google-analytics.com/ga.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var pageTracker = _gat._getTracker("UA-XXXXXX-1");
    pageTracker._setDomainName(".mydomain.com");
    pageTracker._trackPageview();    
</script>
```

I need to change a the last line in the script to `pageTracker._trackPageview("Success");` at run time. The Google Analytics injects this script at some point in the page building process. It's a bit tricky because once the Google Analytics module is added, it runs for all pages requested and puts this scrip at the end of the body tag.

Is there a way to examine the HTML, parse it, find that line and edit it? What's the best way to accomplish that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

`SiteAnalytics.config`, located in the DNN root, allows you to globally modify the analytics script and have some control over where it is injected.

I have used it to load the new asychronous analytics script to `<body>` instead of `<head>`, in order to avoid the the problem in the default configuration, where [title element is positioned after the script](http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Resources/Forums/forumid/108/postid/347597/scope/posts.aspx), and "Content by Title" reports won't work.

#### See Also

- [How to set up Google Analytics asynchronous tracking in DotNetNuke
  (the ‘new’ version of the GA tracking code)](http://seoandppcblog.wordpress.com/2011/03/06/how-to-set-up-google-analytics-asynchronous-tracking-in-dotnetnuke-the-new-version-of-the-ga-tracking-code/)